# How to default a table search results to hidden with AngularJS filters?

Tags: angularjs

In the following Angularjs snippet, an entire table is shown by default and gets filtered down as you start typing.

1. What would be best practice to change it to show no results by default and only start showing results after, say, at least 3 results match the search query?
2. Bonus question, how would you go about only displaying results if a minimum of 2 characters have been entered?

**Html**:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search.$">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="person in population.sample | filter:search">
                <td>{{person.name}}</td>
                <td>{{person.job}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Main.js**:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('Population', function () {
    var Population = {};
    Population.sample = [
        {
            name: "Bob",
            job: "Truck driver"
        }
        // etc.
    ];
    return Population;
});

function PeopleCtrl($scope, Population) {
    $scope.people = Population;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do all of that in your markup, actually... [here's a plunk to demonstrate](http://plnkr.co/edit/wPsD0rsC8zMIHXakKJJY?p=preview)

And here's the change in your markup:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
<table ng-show="(filteredData = (population.sample | filter:search)) && filteredData.length >= 3 && search && search.length >= 2">
    <tr ng-repeat="person in filteredData">
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.job}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT: changed my answer to reflect your requests.**

Comment: Not quite. So the question is no results by default which is achieved by making `ng-show` to be `filteredData = (filter:search)` but then no results appear.

Comment: Edited my answer, it should now only show the answers if your search string is more than two characters long and there are 3 or more results.

Comment: That's better. I want to accept this answer but before I do that I want to ask... is adding so much logic to ng-show acceptable (context: I use Rails where view logic is frowned upon) and would it not be better elsewhere?

Comment: It's really the cleanest way to cache filtered results. It's either that or in your controller, you'll need to inject `$filter` and then create instances of your filters, then use them, then put the results in a `$scope` variable. So, yes, it's generally acceptable. However, if you find it to be too hard to maintain for some reason, well, move it to your controller.